# Android focus with getChildAt

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I'm facing the problem with listView, editText and adjustResize. I tried to solve it with a listener that detect when the softkeyboard pop, and I do the focus after.

But the problem is when I try to focus an editText of my listView with getChildAt, it's okay while there is no need to scroll, but if there is a scrollbar, the editText I want to focus is  not anymore in the child list of the listView.

I read some stuff on getChild functions, and it only keep what's displayed. So I tried to move the visible part of the listView with setSelection() but my editText is still not in the getChild list.

Here is some code of the activity :

```
currentListView.setSelection(currentListView.getChildCount());

                    for ( int i = 0; i < currentListView.getChildCount(); i ++){
                        System.out.println(currentListView.getChildAt(i)+"");
                    }
```

This is of course the most interesting part and I think I'm missing android knowledge. But of course you can ask for more explanations or code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int pos, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // play with items clicked .... u will get position of item in pos
}
```

Use Item Click event of list view like ,

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

you can play with ur items cliecked in this event. and can also get the position of the items clicked in int pos.